# Why do I get a delay when executing animations first time?

Tags: objective-c, ios, animation

I am using `imageWithContentsOfFile:` to load my .png images into an array. When the `IBAction` triggers the animation, there is a noticeable delay before the animation starts. Then, each time after that, it executes smoothly. I originally tried to load them with the `imageNamed:` method but experienced the same delay plus big performance problems on the device.

Comment: Do you load the images right when the animation begins? If so, I recommend that you instead load them maybe when the view is initialized or when you aren't performing intensive operations, so by the time the animation rolls around, the images are already in memory.

Comment: I am loading them in viewDidLoad. Should I try to init them before that?

Comment: Use the developer tool Instruments (built into xcode).

Answer (score 0):

Load the images in ViewWillLoad instead.

If that doesn't work, use the developer tool Instruments (built into xcode) to find what is causing the performance hit. Choose Open GL ES driver, under the iOS -> graphics menu. Then tick Hide system libraries. Then it will show you which methods are taking a long time, click into those methods to see exactly which lines, then just try and figure out alternative ways to do it.